# Disable main ui widget from sub ui widget in separate files

Tags: python, pyqt

I have 2 ui files - `main_ui` and `sub_ui`

When the main_ui is opened, there is a QPushButton and a QListWidget.
If user clicks on the QPushButton, it will open the sub_ui.

On the other hand, there is only a QPushButton in the sub_ui.
If user clicks on this QPushButton, it should disabled the `listWidget` in the main_ui.

I am having issues with the disabling. 
While there is nothing of error prompted, I am unable to get the listWidget disabled.

This is my `main_ui` code:

```
class MainUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        self.init_main_ui()
        self.main_signals()
        self.setFixedSize(QtCore.QSize(300, 600))

    def init_main_ui(self):
        self.mainBtn = QtGui.QPushButton("show sub ui")
        self.listWidget = QtGui.QListWidget(self)

        self.mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.mainBtn)
        self.mainLayout.addWidget(self.listWidget)

        self.setLayout(self.mainLayout)

    def main_signals(self):
        self.mainBtn.clicked.connect(self.onClicked)

    def onClicked(self):
        subUI = SubUI()
        subUI.show()
```

This is my `sub_ui` code:

```
import main_ui

class SubUI(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(SubUI, self).__init__(parent=parent)
        subLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        subBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Testing')

        subLayout.addWidget(subBtn)
        subBtn.clicked.connect(self.disable_list)

    def disable_list(self):
        mainUI = main_ui.MainUI()
        mainUI.listWidget.setEnabled(False)
```

How do I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

Change `onClicked` as follows:

```
def onClicked(self):
    subUI = SubUI()
    subUI.subBtn.clicked.connect(self.disable_list)
    subUI.show()
```

Move `disable_list` to MainUI and change it like this:

```
 def disable_list(self):
    self.listWidget.setEnabled(False)
```

Delete the `subBtn.clicked.connect` call from SubUI (it got moved to `onClicked`).

Make subBtn a member variable of SubUI so you can access it from `onClicked`.

```
self.subBtn = QtGui.QPushButton('Testing')
subLayout.addWidget(self.subBtn)
```

Comment: I am not understanding the latter part - `Make subBtn a member variable of SubUI so you can access it from onClicked`

Comment: But I am still curious though - why is it not possible to do it in the similar fashion I have done as in my initial code

Comment: @Yan Aren't you recreating the main UI when trying to disabling list in main ?

Comment: @LaurentG I am not exactly sure what you meant by `recreate` but my idea is that as the main ui is open, when user clicks on the button that pops up the sub ui (something like an advanced option window), if a certain selection is done within sub ui, in this case if the `subBtn` is pressed, it will disables the listWidget in main and I need this `subBtn` to be in sub ui

Comment: `mainUI = main_ui.MainUI()` is a call to the mainUI constructor, no ? Why do you want to do that ?

Comment: Sorry for the delay in this reply.  You want the `SubUI` object to control a component (`listWidget`) of the MainUI object.  To do that, the code inside `SubUI` needs to have a reference to `listWidget` - in other words, a variable name which allows it to modify the state of `listWidget`.  You tried to do that in your `disable_list` function, but the code you wrote created a new `MainUI` window, rather than accessing the one that already exists.  As you code stands, there is no variable in `SubUI` that represents the `MainUI` window. --continued--

Comment: An alternative - in my opinion, better - way is for `MainUI` to create an event handler that responds to a click of `subBtn`.  That's what my solution does.  But you didn't make `subBtn` a member variable of `SubUI`, it's just a local variable inside `__init__`.  Code in `MainUI` has no way of accessing it.  That's the meaning of my sentence that you say you didn't understand.  Once `subBtn` is made a member variable of `SubUI`, I can access it from `MainUI` code.  I chose this approach because allowing object B to modify the internal state of object A is rarely a good idea.